# Allow AppleScript script to run without asking for permission

Tags: macos, applescript

Hi I am using osascript `tell process "Terminal"` in a bash script.

It obviously need permission for doing this. It asks me for sudo, but I would like to signe go give this script access to run without interacting. Can you do that?

Full osascript  call

```
osascript <<END
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Terminal"
            click menu item "Merge All Windows" of menu "Window" of menu bar 1
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
END
```

Note: this is within a shell script.

Comment: *How* are you using that exactly? What error does it give?

Comment: no errors - I just have to login like if you do sudo "something".

Comment: Why do you need to do any `sudo`? I can do this easily enough without any questions or logging in... `osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "date"'`

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I hav updated the question with the full osascript call.

Comment: Just a quick hint up front: Both Bash and `sudo` are incidental to the problem. The error message your code produces is `System Events got an error: osascript is not allowed assistive access. (-1719)`, indicating the absence of required authorization for programmatic control of the UI.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Update*: [Dominik Bucher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5774854/dominik-bucher) reports that **the solution below doesn't work on macOS High Sierra and above**, seemingly by design.

---

What your AppleScript is doing is an instance of **GUI scripting** - controlling the user interface programmatically.

GUI scripting requires that the **application performing it** - `Terminal.app` in this case, assuming you're running your Bash script from there<sup>[1]</sup> - be **authorized for assistive access** in `System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility`.

<sup>You are offered to be taken to the relevant System Preferences pane *the very first time* you open an application (or run a script from within it) that's not yet authorized. You can always manage applications there later manually. Only *checked* applications are currently authorized.</sup>

This is a **one-time, per-application, for-all-users configuration step that *itself* requires administrative privileges** (authentication via **interactive prompt**), but once an application has been authorized, ***running* such a script no longer requires admin privileges**.
(`sudo` never enters the picture with respect to GUI scripting.)

See [Apple's support article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202802) on the subject (written at the time of OS X 10.9, but still applies as of 10.11).

**Caveat**: Since authorization is at the *application* level, **authorizing `Terminal.app` then allows *any* script run from it to perform GUI scripting.**

---

There is an - undocumented - way to ***programmatically* authorize an application**, where administrative authentication is provided via `sudo`; e.g., to authorize `Terminal.app`, use the following - note that unless already authenticated, `sudo` still *prompts* for the admin password:

- OS X 10.11 (El Capitan):

`sudo sqlite3 /Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db "REPLACE INTO access values ('kTCCServiceAccessibility', 'com.apple.Terminal', 0, 1, 1, NULL, NULL);"`

- OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) and 10.9 (Mavericks):

`sudo sqlite3 /Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db "REPLACE INTO access values ('kTCCServiceAccessibility', 'com.apple.Terminal', 0, 1, 1, NULL);"`

For background, see [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/111903/28668) (as of this writing, it needs updating for El Capitan).

---

As far as I know, there's **no way to sign an individual application / applet in a way that *pre*-authorizes assistive access.**
(Additionally, signed AppleScript applets may invalidate their - manually granted - authorization by self-modification - see the linked Apple Support article above.)

---

<sup>[1] **Authorization is granted at the level of *OS X applications* (`*.app` bundles)**, so a script that performs GUI scripting requires that the *application* running the script be authorized - as opposed to a command-line program such as `osascript` *inside* an application that is actually interpreting the script (even though the error message may - misleadingly - implicate that program; e.g., `osascript is not allowed assistive access`).</sup>

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, @DominikBucher - I've added a note at the beginning of the answer.

Comment: Thanks, @Dominik. I appreciate the nice feedback.